# Google+ get userID using e-mail?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I want to know if it is possible to get the "userId" value using the Google+ api, in order to display a link to some specific user profile. For better explanation, I have a PHP application and there is a panel where I can view the existing users in my database. So, when detailing a specific user, I want to show a Google+ badge which will link to that user's Google+ profile. I don't have the "userId", but still have access to his email address. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no endpoint that you can hit to convert an email address into a Google+ userId.

However, you can use the REST API to determine the Google+ userId of the currently logged in user. This will require the user to grant you access to their identity on Google+ via OAuth.  To do this use the [people get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) endpoint with me as the userId. You can try this out on the [API Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=plus&_v=v1&_m=people.get&userId=me) to observe what the user experience with the OAuth dialog will be like.

Here's some code lifted from the [PHP starter project](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-php-starter/) that illustrates everything you need to fetch the userId of the current user:

```
if (ini_get('register_globals') === "1") {
 die("register_globals must be turned off before using the starter application");
}

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiPlusService.php';

session_start();

$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("Google+ PHP Starter Application");
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and to register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
$client->setClientId('insert_your_oauth2_client_id');
$client->setClientSecret('insert_your_oauth2_client_secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('insert_your_oauth2_redirect_uri');
$client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_developer_key');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
$plus = new apiPlusService($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $me = $plus->people->get('me');
  // Do stuff with the id
  echo $me['id'];

  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is an endpoint for converting an e-mail address into a Google+ ID: `http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/**replace-with-email-address**?alt=json`. It's not well documented, so I wouldn't rely on it for anything major.